# Proposed Community WIKI suggestions

Tags: discussion, support

I was reviewing questions seeking help in resolving issues the various posters of the respective questions had with different aspects of Blender. Now, while the particular questions I was paying most attention to dealt with modeling issues, I noticed questions about other areas of Blender, too: animation, texturing, rendering, &c., and it occurred to me that what many of the questioners needed more than they needed an answer, was a guide to how to find the answers to their questions themselves. Of the books I have read, the tutorials I have reviewed, and discussions I have followed, not once have I found a resource which, given a particular type of problem, say some tool not working as expected, presents a list of suggested steps in how to help a user find the answer.

What do you think about the idea of a series of pages, titled, "When you have a problem with >    <, here are some things to look for to solve the problem."? As a concrete example, a recent question asked about an interrupted loop cut, but I suspect that the person who asked the question didn't think (or didn't know) to switch to vertex select mode, in which the problem would have been quickly identified. I remember another question about textures not appearing which the answer was simply that the one asking the question had the display mode set to solid. I expect that a current question about why a render is all gray will turn out to be similarly trivial to solve.

I think a good format is to write a "question" introducing the check lists, and have a series of answers, one for each area of blender, where things to look for are posted, somewhat on the format of the "Resources for Blender" question.

Comment: I think you're right. There are a lot of questions that get answers that are extremely quick, and I have to wonder if they're duplicates. I think we do need some sort of resource that we can at least point to for those types of cases, but I'm not sure if the format you're suggesting is the way to go. I feel like you're more just throwing ideas around that things that are written in stone anyway.

Comment: @TARDISMaker On occasion, I've done some keyword searches on some of these questions, and have found that some of them are duplicates. Of course, they're not seen as duplicates by those who are new to Blender and new to Blender SE, and are asking the questions.